# Information sought on filesystems and high-performance memory-mapped data stores on Windows

Tags: performance, winapi, filesystems

I've recently acquired responsibility for a critical system which is a data store featuring memory-mapped IO, multi-threaded (local) clients, and an interesting mixture of constraints. It has to store a mix of serial and indexed data including sparse 3D data of varying levels of detail.

Performance is critical, including being able to work with gigabytes of data on Win32 including working on XP but I only have to worry about Windows implementations. It is mostly implemented but I have to worry about debugging and improving performance.

I'm looking for tips on where to study, book recommendations, themes etc. I have a varied 25+ years experience including writing Quicktime components and a lot of work with ISAM data stores but not having to worry about the finer points of performance and cache coherence in this kind of system. I don't have  traditional computer science education so if there's a theoretical gap I need to fill, please tell me!

Areas I was considering are the data stores used for some games, file system implementations, git internals and books such as Maurice Herlihy's [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916).

Comment: I once worked with a principal developer at Microsoft with many years of experience coding inside the filesystem kernel. He had nothing but bad things to say about the memory mapping facilities in Windows, indicating that high-performance code should never use it. I will confess to a fair degree of ignorance on the subject myself, so this is an unbridled appeal to authority, but hopefully it suggests an avenue of investigation that might bear fruit.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I already had a headache :-/

I haven't heard about the memory-mapped implementation being poorly implemented but based on your feedback spent a while searching. I found this interesting post about mapping failing on XP for portions of files around 2TB "CreateFileMapping failing for large files - ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA in Win32 Kernel" http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32453533/createfilemapping-failing.aspx